# JQuery CSS code doesn't center in the middle of the window

Tags: jquery, css, window, center, centering

I have this code here

http://forum.castoff.net/menu.php

And the msgbox comes up in the middle of the whole page... I need it to come up in the middle of the viewable area..

Could anyone help ??

I am sure its just a CSS issue

Thanks

Lee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is on `.msgbox`, change `position: absolute` to `position: fixed`.

That's it.

Read this to understand the different `position` values:
http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/

Comment: Perfect solution... Any clues why the dimming background and msgbox don't go over a youtube embedded video ?? i've added to the URL to show you

Comment: That's really a separate question, but it's been asked many times before, so: you basically need `wmode` = `transparent`, twice: once like this: `<param name="wmode" value="transparent"></param>`, and once inside your `embed` tag: `<embed .. wmode="transparent" ..></embed>`.

Answer (score 0):

You're giving "dim" a top-position of 50%, so it will be at 50% of the page, not the viewable area.

Try centering it with this:

```
function centerMe(element) {
    //pass element name to be centered on screen
    var pWidth = $(window).width();
    var pTop = $(window).scrollTop()
    var eWidth = $(element).width()
    var height = $(element).height()
    $(element).css('top', pTop + 100+'px')
    $(element).css('left', parseInt((pWidth / 2) - (eWidth / 2)) + 'px')
}
```

Comment: Hi Diodeus, I've put that code in and given it the element id but its still centering to the whole page not the viewable area :-(

Comment: Remove your top/left styling in CSS for msgbox. For the script to work, "msgbox" should not be a child of "dim". It should be a child of "body".

Answer (score 0):

The `table` and the `#dim` have height `2000px` and over, so giving `top:50%` for the popup put it in the middle of it's parent. Remove the height of the `table` and see if this do the job (probably will works, because the height of `#dim` is the height of the document.).

Another option is to add a fixed value for the distance from top for the `.msgbox`. For example in your css you can change the `.msgbox {top:50%;}` to `.msgbox {top:200px;}`